# Android - how to add button click event inside a TabActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to understand the tab activities in android.. and working around with few examples.I have three tabs Tab1,Tab2,Tab3.. in which when I click each tab it will display a simple textview.this is fine for me.Now, I added a button in Tab1 and I tired to handle the click event... its not working for me.It says "App has stopped".
Below is the Tab1 activity....

EDIT1:I am a starter..In Android sdk it comes with a default API demo project.In that project, for 2.x Andriod OS.. the same method works.They are able to handle this click event in that ta activity.

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity
{
    private Button bt_AddAcc = null;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.bt_addaccount);

            bt_AddAcc = (Button)findViewById(R.layout.bt_addaccount);
            bt_AddAcc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uername:",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TabActivity` is already deprecated.

I suggest you look at the `ActionBar` or when you want to develop for Android 2.x as well then take a look at `ActionBarSherlock`. This is a third party library which implements the `ActionBar` on older devices.

Comment: I am a starter..In Android sdk it comes with a default API demo project.In that project, for 2.x Andriod OS.. the same method works.They are able to handle this click event in that ta activity.